# Docker-Compose cannot find docker-compose.yml

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

I create a docker-compose file in the /srv/postgresql as below.

```sh
xxx@xxxx:/srv/postgresql$ ls -all
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 xxx xxx 4096 Dec 15 04:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 Dec 15 04:08 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 xxx xxx 251 Dec 15 04:07 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxr-x 2 xxx xxx 4096 Dec 15 03:48 postgres_data
```

But when I tried to run `docker-compose up` it says cannot find a suitable configuration file.

```
xxx@xxxx:/srv/postgresql$ docker-compose up
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

It actually works when I move my docker-compose.yml to "/home/xxx/". So I thought it might be some Linux file permission issues. Can anyone explain why it happens and how to solve it?

Comment: The docker-compose.yml file is normally in its own application directory with no other files.

Comment: I did remove everything except docker-compose.yml in the directory. But it still not works.